# ThinkPad E14 G2 with Pop!_Os reboots after resuming from S3 suspend

Tags: suspend, reboot, thinkpad, pop-os

**Summary:** After suspending, Pop!Os always reboots approx. 20 seconds after resuming.

**Long story:** I recently installed Pop!_Os 20.04 LTS on my new Lenovo Thinkpad E14 Gen2 Intel. I am running the 5.13.0-7614-generic kernel.
Everything worked like a charm, except that I was not satisfied with the battery consumption in suspend mode. I found out that s2idle was my standard suspend mode and changed it to "deep" / S3 / suspend-to-RAM by changing to `mem_sleep_default=deep` in kernelstub boot options. Journal confirmed the successful change, however, ever since I have the problem described above. This happens both when suspending by closing the lid and   when suspending manually.

Some people seem to have had this problem with Ubuntu on different machines and resolved it by changing "acpi_sleep" option to "nonvs". I tried this along the options "s3_mode" and "s3_bios", but all did not resolve the issue.

If anyone has ideas how to fix this, I am glad! Now I am back to s2idle, but the battery consumption of around 1-2%/hour is a lot...

I'll gladly provide console output or any other information you might need.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:** after BIOS update and switching in bios suspend mode to "Windows and Linux" touchpad and trackpad became working normally after suspend.

In my case, after suspend it took about 10-15 seconds before reboot, during this period TrackPad didn't work and in `dmesg` repeatedly appears next line:

```
elan_i2c 0-0015: failed to read report data: -71
```

In some thread on ubuntu's bug tracker, someone suggested disabling trackpad and/or touchpad. For me, disabling both solved the issue with suspend.

Personally don't see any reason to use thinkpad without trackpad, so turned it on and just living with suspend problem.

Comment: Did it work for you? If it worked for you, then this may be a useful suggestion. If it didn’t work for you, then this is just an unsupported, wild guess.  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.